# Working with Search in a UITableView with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `UITableView` where all the details from the `root->Data` node is getting fetched successfully. I'm trying to implement a `SearchController` to filter the data, but it doesn't seem to fetch the search results and bind to the `UITableView`.

My Firebase JSON Structure is as follows:

```
"Data" : {
    "01" : {
      "priority" : 2,
      "search" : "school centre",
      "title" : "School Centre"
    },
```

Here is the code from the `updateSearchResults`:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
    }

    func filterContent(searchText:String)
    {
        if (searchText.count == 0){
            observePosts()
        } else {
            print(searchText)
            observeSearchPosts(searchText: searchText)
        }
    }
```

The only difference between `observePosts` and `observeSearchPosts` is the database reference line:

```
func observeSearchPosts(searchText: String) {
    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("Data").queryOrdered(byChild: "search").queryStarting(atValue: searchText)
    print(postsRef)
    postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        for child in snapshot.children{

            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                let logoImage = dict["image"] as? String,
                let url = URL(string:logoImage),
                let address = dict["address"] as? String,
                let contact = dict["contact"] as? String,
                let description = dict["description"] as? String{


                let userProfile = UserProfile(title: title, photoURL: url)
                let post = Post(id: childSnapshot.key, title: userProfile, description: description, image: userProfile, address: address, contact: contact)
                print(post)
                tempPosts.append(post)
            }
        }
        self.posts = tempPosts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

In `observePosts` the database reference is `let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("Data").queryOrdered(byChild: "priority")`.

Answer (score 1):

fetch all data from firebase and then use search in local array post....!
and then reload tableview